# Make Button Toggle a GameObject On and Off

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

I'm stuck on this one. I have two buttons that are each associated with a respective pop-up that I would like to show when the buttons are clicked and then hide when the buttons are clicked again and so on. I know I need to invert the boolean using '!' but I'm not exactly sure how to implement it in my code below. What is the correct way that my PaletteState function should be written? Thanks!

```
using UnityEngine ;
using System.Collections ;
using UnityEngine.UI ;

public class ShowHidePalettes : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button changeColorButton ;
    public GameObject colorPalette ;
    public Button brushSizeButton ;
    public GameObject brushSizePalette ;

    void Awake ()
    {
        changeColorButton.onClick.AddListener (() => PaletteState (colorPalette, true)) ;
        brushSizeButton.onClick.AddListener (() => PaletteState (brushSizePalette, true)) ;
    }

    void Start ()
    {
        PaletteState (colorPalette, false) ;
        PaletteState (brushSizePalette, false) ;
    }

    public void PaletteState (GameObject _palette, bool _visible)
    {
        _visible = !_visible ;

        if (_visible == true)
        {
            _palette.SetActive (true) ;
        } else
        {
            _palette.SetActive (false) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two `boolean` variables for each `Button` since each `Button` control two different UI/popup. You flip the respective `boolean` variable when the Button is clicked with the '`!`'. You can then pass in the boolean variable to the `SetActive` function.

Also, you need a way to determine which `Button` is pressed. You can use two different functions for that but using one and passing the `Button` instance is better.

You should also remove listener with `RemoveListener` in the `OnDisable` function since you subscribed to one.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ShowHidePalettes : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button changeColorButton;
    public GameObject colorPalette;
    bool showColorPalette = false;

    public Button brushSizeButton;
    public GameObject brushSizePalette;
    bool showSizeButton = false;

    void Start()
    {
        colorPalette.SetActive(false);
        brushSizePalette.SetActive(false);
    }

    void buttonCallBack(Button buttonClicked)
    {
        //Change Color Palette Button clicked
        if (buttonClicked == changeColorButton)
        {
            showColorPalette = !showColorPalette;//Flip
            colorPalette.SetActive(showColorPalette);
        }

        //Change Brush Size Button Button clicked
        if (buttonClicked == brushSizeButton)
        {
            showSizeButton = !showSizeButton;//Flip
            brushSizePalette.SetActive(showSizeButton);
        }
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        changeColorButton.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(changeColorButton));
        brushSizeButton.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(brushSizeButton));
    }


    void OnDisable()
    {
        changeColorButton.onClick.RemoveListener(() => buttonCallBack(changeColorButton));
        brushSizeButton.onClick.RemoveListener(() => buttonCallBack(brushSizeButton));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Remove the *bool _visible* parameter from **PaletteState** method.
- Then alternate GameObject state by itself.

```
    public void PaletteState (GameObject _palette)
    {
        _palette.SetActive (!palette.activeSelf) ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something like this :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ShowHidePalettes : MonoBehaviour
{

public Button changeColorButton;
public GameObject colorPalette;
public Button brushSizeButton;
public GameObject brushSizePalette;

private bool colorPalleteVisibility = false;
private bool brushSizePalleteVisibility = false;

public void PaletteState(PaleteType type)
{
    if (type == PaleteType.ColorPalette)
    {
        colorPalleteVisibility = !colorPalleteVisibility;
        colorPalette.SetActive(colorPalleteVisibility);
    }
    else if (type == PaleteType.BrushSizePalette)
    {
        brushSizePalleteVisibility = !brushSizePalleteVisibility;
        colorPalette.SetActive(brushSizePalleteVisibility);
    }
}
}
public enum PaleteType
{
ColorPalette, BrushSizePalette
}
```